# Java How to programm Deitel Book exercise 6.35

Tags: java

I've been studying Deitel's Book(Java how to program) and I want to solve exercise 6.35. Here's what it asks:

Write a program to assist a student to learn multiplication.Use a Random object to produce two positive integers (one digit each).
The program should show on screen something like this:("How much is 7 times 3")

Then the student should insert the answer and the program controls if the answer is correct or wrong.If it's correct the program continue asking another question,else the program waits until the student answer is correct.For every new question it must be a new method created(this method should be called once when the application starts and when the user answers correct to a question).

How do I do this?

//I have a problem inside the do-while block!

```
      package multiplication;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

/*Hey again! I've been trying to solve this problem using NetBeans environment
 *
 */


public class Ypologismos
{
    private int p;
    private int a,b;

    public Ypologismos(int a,int b,int p)
    {
        this.a=a;
        this.b=b;
        this.p=p;

    }


 public Ypologismos()
 {


 }






 public void Screen()
 {
     System.out.println("Wrong answer ....please retry");
 }






    public void askForNumbers()
    {
        Random r=new Random();

        int a,b;
        a=r.nextInt(10);
        b=r.nextInt(10);
        int p;//p=product
        p=(a*b);
        System.out.println("How much is:"+" "+a+" "+"times"+" "+b+" "+"?");

        System.out.println("Please insert your answer!");

       Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
       int ans;//ans=answer
       ans=s.nextInt();

       do
       {
           while(ans==p){

               System.out.println("Well done!");
               askForNumbers();
           }

       }while(ans!=p);


    }






}
```

//and my main class ...

```
package multiplication;


public class Main
{


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Ypologismos application=new Ypologismos();

        application.askForNumbers();


    }

}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Do you have any code?  Also, what's your question?

Comment: You need to show a lot more effort here - Have you broken it down into smaller tasks? what's tripping you up?

Comment: @Devilhorn Please add any code to your question inside a code block (indent 4 spaces at the start).

Comment: Additional info should go into the original question (just to preempt a comment code dump)!

Comment: I have also created main and created an object Ypologismos

Comment: Sorry for the comments and the pritnln in greek

Comment: No TAsk it's not a homework I 've been trying to learn java on my own!

Comment: Since the exercise is numbered 6.35 I assume there are a couple of exercises before which cover reading user input from the console, using loops etc. What you learned there should be applied here.

Comment: Yes I know it but I'm not sure about the structure of my program.You see I don't know how to do some things....For instance do I need to write all the multiplication into a method?(to control if the number entered by the user is correct)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a terse story book of how to do it.

```
teach multiplication:
    repeat // solving problems
       int first number = something random
       int second number = something random
       int product = first number * second number
       repeat
           int answer = ask how much is first number times second number
           if answer != product
               say error!
       until answer == product
       say solved!
```

The above is just a first idea, not necessarily following the requirements. But it clears which loop comes in which loop and so on.

---

***Reading your extended question***

```
public class Ypologismos {

    /** Entry point to the application. */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Ypologismos application = new Ypologismos();
        application.teachMultiplication();
    }

    private void teachMultiplication() {
        while (wantsAProblem()) {
             askAProblem();
        }
    }

    private void askAProblem() {
        int αλφα = random.nextInt(10);
        int βητα = random.nextInt(10);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes ,this is what I wanted and I just couldn't think it cause I was confused thank you very much...Now I'm able to think it and finish it by myself :)